# Writing to XML file in foreach loop

Tags: c#, xml, csv, foreach

I have a CSV file with 1 header line and 3 lines of elements, delimited by the "`;`" character. I'm trying to convert this file to an XML file; however, when I view the resulting file, only the last line of elements are present (the other two are missing). How I can create a loop to read and insert all lines from the input file and write them to the XML output file?

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);

foreach (var line in lines)
{
      var csvItem = line.Split(";");

      XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(savepath, Encoding.UTF8);

      writer.WriteStartDocument();
      writer.WriteStartElement("DC8_Recipes");

      writer.WriteStartElement("DC8_Recipes");
      writer.WriteAttributeString("PlantNo", csvItem[1]);
      writer.WriteAttributeString("No", csvItem[2]);
      writer.WriteAttributeString("Name", csvItem[3]);
      writer.WriteStartElement("RecipeSetValueRow");
      writer.WriteAttributeString("SetValue", csvItem[12]);
      writer.WriteAttributeString("EnumSetValueRowUnit", csvItem[11]);
      writer.WriteStartElement("Material");
      writer.WriteAttributeString("No", csvItem[10]);
      writer.WriteEndElement();
      writer.WriteEndElement();
      writer.WriteEndElement();

      writer.WriteEndElement();
      writer.WriteEndDocument();
      writer.Close();
}
```

Comment: (hint: use an existing CSV-parser instead of writing your own). you're opening, writing and closing your output file _once for each iteration_. what you wanna do instead is open it once _before_ your loop and close it once _after_.

Comment: Now there is the loop but, he print in the XML file also the header of the CSV file. How I can skip the header?

Comment: option 1) use an existing CSV-parser that does this for you automatically. option 2) loop over `lines.Skip(1)`.